# How Can I Count Repeat Characters in a Str

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

everyone I was just wondering how to count repeat in ch in a str, the function I wrote is:

```
def repeat(s):
    '''
    '''
    count = 0 
    L = []

    for i in range(len(s)):
        count = 0
        if s[i] in s: 
         count = count + 1
        else:
             count = count

    L.append(count)
    return L
```

But, the list will repeat itself if the letters are the same. Is there a better way of counting the amount of characters in a str? I was thinking of using a dictionary?

Comment: What should this function return for a sample string?

Comment: This question is hard to understand which is why you have 2 very different answers so far. `s[i] in s` will always be true. Your function doesn't make any sense. Improve your question by describing what you want or fixing your function to give a correct result. I wonder who upvoted this question in it's current state.

Answer (score 5):

Counting the number of characters in a string is done like this:

```
len(my_str)
```

So if you want to count the number of repeat characters, it would be

```
len(my_str) - len(set(my_str))
```

This is equivalent to:

> total number of characters - the number of unique characters.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear at the moment, but if you're trying to count the number of times each character appears in a string, this will work:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> char_counts = Counter(s)
```

Example:

```
>>> d = Counter("Chris Doggett")
>>> for k, v in d.iteritems():
...    print k, v
  1
C 1
e 1
D 1
g 2
i 1
h 1
o 1
s 1
r 1
t 2

>>> print d
Counter({'g': 2, 't': 2, ' ': 1, 'C': 1, 'e': 1, 'D': 1, 'i': 1, 'h': 1, 'o': 1, 's': 1, 'r': 1})
```

Counter will basically give you a dictionary of your iterable with each item as the key, and the number of times that key appears as the value.

And if you just want the list of characters that show up multiple times, it's a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> [k for k in d if d[k] > 1]
['g', 't']
```